# Windows CE 2013 Development enviornment

Tags: windows, visual-studio-2012, windows-ce

I am very new to Windows CE development. I have understood that I can develop mobile applications using Windows CE. Can anyone tell me the environmental set up needed to develop a  Windows CE Application. I know Visual Studio 2012 can be used, anything else.

Please consider that I am very young in this platform, Thanks.

Comment: http://geekswithblogs.net/WernerWillemsens/archive/2013/09/13/building-windows-ce-6-or-7-smart-device-application-with.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are developing application for WEC2013 (Windows CE 2013), you should have Visual Studio 2012.

Along with VS2012, You need to have SDK for the device.